# Multiple types on a deque?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

This is non-Boost C++11.  What's the best option for a single stack-like container for two different types?  Something that'd work like this imaginary scenario:

```
template<typename T>
deque <pair<T, v8::Local<v8::Value>>> my_queue;

uint32_t aUint = ...;
v8::Local<v8::Value> value1 = ...;
v8::Local<v8::String> aString = ...;
v8::Local<v8::Value> value2 = ...;

my_queue.push_back(make_pair(aUint, value1));
my_queue.push_back(make_pair(aString, value2));
```

Comment: Why would you want to re-invent `boost::variant`? Just use `boost::variant`.

Comment: Well if you can't use `boost::variant`, you can use a `union` but it's a lot less typesafe and you'll have to be careful.

Comment: This is for a public npm module. I've run into issues with users being unable to compile modules due to Boost dependencies. Got a reasonable solution to that?

Comment: @DougLuce Depending on the licensing of your module, I think you can bundle part of boost (just the parts you need) in with your code instead of depending on global boost installation.

Comment: @DougLuce I'm not familiar with that npm code, but it looks like `v8::Value` already supports a kind of variadic data containment. Why not wrap that with code necessary to make it compliant for C++ standard containers?

Comment: Be lazy, write a type with both members as fields and a bool saying which is active.  Rsvisit if performance/size *really* matters, after you prove it?

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, that's what I did for the [actual code](https://github.com/allenluce/mmap-object/blob/master/mmap-object.cc#L47). I'm now revisiting.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses [`std::experimental::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any/any) to do this.

```
#include <experimental/any>                                                                                                                                                                                  
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<std::experimental::any> d;
    d.push_back(1);
    d.push_back(std::make_pair(3, 2));
}
```

I don't really know if this fits your requirements (it's obviously not strictly standard c++11). FWIW, it builds using g++-5 with `--std=c++1y`.